# Запись ArrayList в ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, android, потоки-данных

Можно ли передавать в `ObjectOutpurStream` `ArrayList`? И если да, как потом корректно прочитать его с помощью `ObjectInputStream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, как объект:

```
final String fileName = "test.txt";
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
try (FileOutputStream  fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos))
{
    oos.writeObject(numbers);
}
catch (IOException ignored) { }
```

И, соответственно, можно потом считать его как объект:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis))
{
    List<Integer> readNumbers = (ArrayList<Integer>)ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(readNumbers);
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ignored) { }
```

При этом нужно не забывать, что объекты в списке должны быть сериализуемыми.

Comment: При касте к `ArrayList` выдаёт `Unchecked cast` warning. Что с этим делать?

Comment: @Evgeniy смириться с этим, либо просто игнорируя предупреждение, либо используя для этого `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Можно, конечно, сделать `Object o = ois.readObject(); if (o instanceof ArrayList) {... }`, но проверки на корректный тип generics этот код всё равно не даст.